# Goto somewhere based on a variable, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, goto

Ok so I'm a kinda new to the whole JavaScript thing but I was just trying something 
 Some kind of yes/no quiz thingy and I want to skip certain questions and stuff 
 
 I came up with the following but the whole "continue Q + question_nr;" doesn't work like I hoped it would. How am I supposed to do this? :)

```js
var question_nr = 1;

Q1:
function q1() {
    var a1 = prompt("Wanna skip the next question?", "y/n");
switch(a1) {
    case "y":
        alert("k");
        question_nr = question_nr + 2;
        continue Q + question_nr;
        break;
    case "n":
        alert("oki");
        question_nr = question_nr + 1;
        break;
    default:
        alert("please enter y or n.");
        break;
 } 
}

Q2:
alert("test2");
//<insert question 2>
break;

Q3:
alert("test3");
//<insert question 3>
break;
```

```html
<button onclick="q1()">test</button>
```

p.s. any good sites to help me learn JS are appreciated so I don't have to ask (probably really stupid) questions like this one in the future

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/ is a good place to start with javascript

Comment: How is it supposed to work :) These are some good free interactive learning sites that are great for learning the basics (You can pay to learn more advanced stuff). https://www.codecademy.com/, http://www.khanacademy.org/cs. Once you have mastered those basic courses I would recoment looking to books. w3schools is also good.

Comment: @WizardCoder It's supposed to like goto Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5 etc based on the value of the variable question_nr.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to teach you, go to the code academy, but if you at least "don't know" how to implement something that works as you want, I can tell you how to do something that works somehow near how goto worked. Listen:

You can declare execution of your questions (let's call that "goto targets") as:

```
const QUESTIONS = {
  Q1: function () {
    someLogicThere();
  },
  Q2: function () {
    someLogicThere();
  }
};
```

And execute it in some way like this (this will throw an error if you don't define any of required questions):

```
switch(lastPrompt) {
    case "y":
        alert("k");
        question_nr = question_nr + 2;
        QUESTIONS["Q" + question_nr]();
        break;
    case "n":
        alert("oki");
        question_nr = question_nr + 1;
        break;
    default:
        alert("please enter y or n.");
        break;
    }   
}
```

But I assume that a bad code. You should wrap everything inside IIFE/module and use more html/angular/react to keep this organised.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are still learning, but you should not use labels to do this. The following is a more simple way to accomplish this goal.

```
(function () {
    var questions = [
        'How much wood can a wood chuck chuck?',
        'How many fish in the sea?',
        'How does this JavaScript work?'
    ];
    var index = -1;
    window.askQuestion = function () {
        var answer = prompt("Wanna skip the next question?", "y/n");
        if(answer === 'y' || answer === 'n') {
            index = (index + 1) + (answer === 'y');
            if(questions[index]) {
                alert(questions[index]);
            } else {
                alert("No more questions to ask.");
                index = -1;
            }
        } else {
            alert("please enter y or n.");
        }
    };
}());
```

A few things to note. The function above wraps its code in what is called a self-executing anonymous function. This makes it so that the variables declared inside it are within a private scope. Next, we store questions inside of an array while keeping in mind that the array index always begins at 0. This is why when we declare the variable for index that it begins at -1. If the answer given by the user is y or n, then we add one to the index plus true or false whether or not the answer is y. This conditionally increments index by 1 if n or 2 if y. Then check whether or not a question exists at the calculated index. If it does, trigger the alert for the question, or if not alert that there are no more questions and reset the index to -1.